# No arrow Google Maps Infowindow

Tags: api, google-maps, infowindow

I have created a custom Google Map using the V3 API.  Infowindows work great on full browsers and tablets for both Macs and PCs.  However the arrow part of the infowindow is non existant in either one of the mobile phone platforms, i.e. iPhone and Android phones.

Any clue as to why only mobile smartphones do not show arrow on infowindow

[URL to site](http://webedit.colgate.edu/about/maps/campus-gmap-searchtemplate) in question:
http://webedit.colgate.edu/about/maps/campus-gmap-searchtemplate

Answer (score 0):

Essentially Google Maps does not like the way BootStrap handels the max-width of images. So you need to put a little hack in your CSS...

```
#map img {
    max-width: none;
}
```